# Creating a string outside of <?php ?>

Tags: php, string

I know you are able to do

```
<?php if ($a == 5): ?>
A is equal to 5
<?php endif; ?>
```

but is it possible to create a string outside a php script?

```
<?php $email_body = ' ?>
<body>
    <h1>This is my email</h1>
    <br/><br/>
    <div>
        <span style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #404040;">This is a test email</span>
    </div>
</body>
<?php '; ?>

<?php
    email($email_body, $to, $from);
?>
```

I want to keep the script formatted in html... but it is kinda ugly when you create a string with html... you can't really format it well.

Comment: Look in [HEREDOC](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc)s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [Heredoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) (or a Nowdoc, in which variables are not interpreted. More info in the same section of the PHP documentation linked)

```
<?php $email_body = <<<EOS
<body>
    <h1>This is my email</h1>
    <br/><br/>
    <div>
        <span style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #404040;">This is a test email</span>
    </div>
</body>
EOS;

email($email_body, $to, $from);
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it using buffers (this way you can use php in your html) :

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>

<body>
    <h1>This is my email the <?=date('d/m/Y')?></h1>
    <br/><br/>
    <div>
        <span style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #404040;">This is a test email</span>
    </div>
</body>

<?php
$html = ob_get_contents();

ob_end_clean();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Do you want this?:

```
<php

$email_body = '<body>
    <h1>This is my email</h1>
    <br/><br/>
    <div>
        <span style="font-family: sans-serif; color: #404040;">This is a test email</span>
    </div>
</body>';

email($email_body, $to, $from);

?>
```